# React , leaflet , Converting or Exporting map into an image or in byte64 format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using React-leaflet for generating a dynamic map using latitudes and longitudes. Now , i have to show that map in a pptx and in doc file. Is there any way i can export this map as an image or in byte64 format , so that i can include that in my generated PPT files.

I tried few examples , but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Leaflet print/export plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport). The [Leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) plugin looks especially promising.